# Concat two path using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, concatenation

I'm not familiar with windows batch script. So, please help me. I want to concat two path using batch file.

I tried :

```
set mypath=%cd% 
@echo %mypath%

unzip -o %mypath%+"\\xpi\\test.xpi" -d %mypath%+"\\Debug\\"
```

But, not working.

So, how to concat two path?

Comment: There is no need for an interim variable `%mypath%`, just use `%CD%` immediately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps try this:

```bat
Set "MyPath=%CD%" 
@Echo=%MyPath%

unzip -o "%MyPath:\=\\%\\xpi\\test.xpi" -d "%MyPath:\=\\%\\Debug\\"
```

If the double backslashes aren't a requirement under Windows then maybe this is all you need:

```bat
Set "MyPath=%CD%" 
@Echo=%MyPath%

unzip -o "%MyPath%\xpi\test.xpi" -d "%MyPath%\Debug\"
```

*In both cases, `unzip` would have to be in `%path%` or local to the batch file.*